# Display Extended-ASCII character in Ruby

Tags: ruby, extended-ascii

How can I print an Extended-ASCII character to the console. For instance if I use the following

```
puts 57.chr
```

It will print "9" to the console. If I were to use

```
puts 219.chr
```

It will only display a "?".  It does this for all of the Extended-ASCII codes from 128 to 254.  Is there a way to display the proper character instead of a "?".

Comment: Note that "Extended ASCII" is an umbrella term, it doesn't refer to a specific character encoding.

Comment: I am trying to using the drawing characters to create graphics in my console program.  I can't use anything like curses. ASCII Code 219 is a solid block.

Comment: You should use Unicode/UTF-8 (unless you have to support legacy systems). See  [Block Elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements) and [Box-drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_Drawing).

Comment: So if for instance, if I was going to use the Unicode character U+2588 (the full block) how would I print that to the console in Ruby.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I am trying to using the drawing characters to create graphics in my console program.

You should use UTF-8 nowadays.

Here's an example using characters from the [Box Drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_Drawing) Unicode block:

```
puts "╔═══════╗\n║ Hello ║\n╚═══════╝"
```

Output:

```
╔═══════╗
║ Hello ║
╚═══════╝
```

> So if for instance I was going to use the Unicode character U+2588 (the full block) how would I print that to the console in Ruby.

You can use:

```
puts "\u2588"
```

or:

```
puts 0x2588.chr('UTF-8')
```

or simply:

```
puts '█'
```

Comment: Thank You.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Most of my programming experience for console applications was for DOS 6.0 and ASCII was still king.  Programming in Windows I never had to worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

You may need to specify the encoding, e.g.:

```
219.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
```

Comment: You can also pass an encoding name, e.g. `219.chr('UTF-8')`

Comment: What is the encoding for Extended_ASCII because UTF-8 does not have the same characters such as the solid block and borders that ASCII does.

Comment: "Extended ASCII" isn't an encoding, as such, so it's difficult to say exactly what your text is using (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII)

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the encoding of the string and then convert it to `UTF-8`. For example if I want to use [Windows-1251](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) encoding:

```
219.chr.force_encoding('windows-1251').encode('utf-8')
# => "Ы"
```

Similarly for `ISO_8859_1`:

```
219.chr.force_encoding("iso-8859-1").encode('utf-8')
# => "Û"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `Integer#chr([encoding])`:

```
219.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)   #=> "Û"
```

more information in [method doc](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-chr).